# How to compute the mean if there is a particular condition to respect?

Tags: python, if-statement, mean

I want to compute the `mean` from the matrix `TBM[x,y]`, where `x` and `y` are respectively the rows and columns. I want to compute the mean over not all rows (let see later why not all), in order to obtain `TBM[s,y]`, where `s` is not equal to `1` but it could be `s < x`. Not all over the rows, because there is a condition: the time; If the `t0 < t < t1` we compute the first mean. Next, we have `t1 < t < t2`, we compute the second mean, and so on...

So I could compute in 2 nested `for` cicle with a condition `if` over the time `t`, and put the `mean` in a new matrix. But how?

EDIT:

```
 for t in time:
     for i in range(kk, len(TBM)-1):
        if (TBM[i,1] > t[j] and TBM[i,1] < t[j+1]):
            sums = sums + TBM[i,2]
            kk = kk + 1
     means[t] = sums / kk
```

But it seems that is not working as I wanted.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want: you seem to mention two conditions. Please reformulate and perhaps provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
count = []
k = 0
for j in range(len(t)-1):
    for i in range(k, len(TBM)-1):
        if (TBM[i] > t[j] and TBM[i] < t[j+1]):
            count.append(i)
            k = k + 1
            break
count.append(len(TBM)-1)        
count = np.asarray(count)

data_mean = np.asarray([[0.0 for j in range(len(count)-1)] for i in range(np.size(TBM[0]))]).T
data_sum = np.asarray([[0.0 for j in range(len(count)-1)] for i in range(np.size(TBM[0]))]).T
for k in range (len(count)-1):
    for j in range(np.size(TBM[0])):
        for i in range (count[k], count[k+1]):
            data_sum[k,j] = data_sum[k,j] + data_tbm1[i,j]
        data_mean[k,j] = data_sum[k,j] / (count[k+1]-count[k])
```